# Angular Test failed Can't bind to 'header' since it isn't a known property of 'app-previewer'

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I'm trying to unit test my AppComponent and get this error :

> Can't bind to 'header' since it isn't a known property of
>   'app-previewer'.
>
> 1. If 'app-previewer' is an Angular component and it has 'header' input, then verify that it is part of this module.

I think it's related to the **@Input** that I'm using to communicate between the parent (EditorComponent) and his child (PreviewerComponent). This error happens only during the test.

**app.component.spec.ts** :

```
describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        EditorComponent,
        PreviewerComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
  it('should create the app', async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  }));
```

**app.component.html** :

```
<app-editor></app-editor>
```

**editor.component.ts** :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Header } from '../model/Header';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./editor.component.css']
})
export class EditorComponent implements OnInit {

  header: Header;

  constructor() {
    this.header = new Header();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**editor.component.html** :

```
<app-previewer [header]="header"></app-previewer>
```

**previewer.component.ts** :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Header } from '../model/Header';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-previewer',
  templateUrl: './previewer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./previewer.component.css']
})
export class PreviewerComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() header: Header;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `attr.`:

```js
<app-previewer [attr.header]="header"></app-previewer>
```

More info: [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives).